# Is there anyway to add display member of combobox to a textbox?

Tags: c#, combobox, datatable

How to set displaymember for below code to a textfield or a listbox ?

```
product_combobox.DataSource = supp;
product_combobox.DisplayMember = "PProduct_name";
product_combobox.ValueMember = "PProduct_id";
```

I am using the below method :

```
string name = product_combobox.SelectedItem.ToString();

textbox1.text= name;
```

but it is not working for me.
I am able to fetch value member though. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead use the below code

```
string name = product_combobox.Text;
textbox1.text= name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
}
```